# Running for-loop and trying to multiply list items

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing

I am trying to run the equation for all the items in the given list (here 3,4,1) in the for loop. Idea is to use a number from list a and a number from range (index number for the list).

So the first one goes ok, 3 * 3^2 + 3 + 5 = 35. This should run through all the items in the list and return [[35, 57, 9]] but gives [[35, 4, 1]] instead. I know it does not run all three items, but what's the thing here I'm missing.

```
def calculate_f(a):

    i=0
    lis = []

    for x in range(0, len(a)):
        
        a[i] = 3 * (a[i]**2) + a[i] + 5

        lis.append(a)
        
        i += 1

        return lis

a = [3,4,1]  
calculate_f(a)
```

Been doing this for three hours and got this far from different error messages, but this almost works :D

Thanks

Comment: [edit] and fix your IndentationErrors - then http://pythontutor.com - step through and inspect.

Comment: btw. you are adding the same list reference over and over so all will point to the same data . You may want to lookup how to copy() or clone() a list.

Comment: Sorry, the editor screwed up the indentations when copy pasteing.

Comment: In your for loop you are doing `for x in range(0, len(a))` but ignoring `x` and instead manually maintaining your own index counter `i`.  You can just use `a[x]`, or even more simply iterate directly over the items in the list with `for x in a:`.  But for more solutions see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
def calculate_f(a):
    return [3 * x ** 2 + x + 5 for x in a]
 
print(calculate_f([3,4,1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, if you want to apply a function to a list of values there are many simpler ways to do it.

First define your function on a single element:

```
>>> def f(x):
...     return 3 * x**2 + x + 5
```

Now there are many ways you can "map" this function to list of values.  For example the built-in `map()`:

```
>>> m = map(f, [3, 4, 5])
>>> m
<map at 0x7f6aa8b00150>
```

This in fact returns an iterable map object that can return each value one at a time:

```
>>> next(m)
35
```

Or you can pass it to `list()`:

```
>>> list(map(f, [3, 4, 5]))
[35, 57, 85]
```

Or you can use a simple `for` loop if you want to get more comfortable with that:

```
>>> m = []
>>> for x in [3, 4, 5]:
...     m.append(f(x))
```

Or the more advanced/succinct version, a list comprehension:

```
>>> m = [f(x) for x in [3, 4, 5]]
>>> m
[35, 57, 85]
```

Or, if you eventually want fast element-wise numerical calculations, get familiar with [NumPy arrays](https://numpy.org/):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> f(np.array([3, 4, 5]))
array([35, 57, 85])
```

Comment: Thanks. Idea here was to do it without Numpy, but thanks for the insights. Gets me going.